# Save option loaded with "foreach" and send var php

Tags: php, html

So, in my database, I have a table that can receive any amount of categories, and when the teacher is creating a course he has to choose from one of them, so I have to show them all and they are loaded into a "select" using a `foreach`. The problem I have is that the value is always the last one and I can't send to another PHP file to insert it into another table. It's easier with the code:

```
<form action="addCurso.php" method="post" name="addcurso" id="addcurso">
              <h3 class="col-md-3">Curso:</h3>
              <div class="col-md-9">
              <input id="addCursoNome" class="form-control" type="text" name="curso" placeholder="Curso">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <h3 class="col-md-3">Thumbnail:</h3>
              <div class="col-md-9">
              <input id="addCursoImg" class="form-control" type="file" name="pic">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <h3 class="col-md-3">Categoria:</h3>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                  <select class="form-control selectpicker">
                    Categoria

                    <?php
                    foreach ($categorias as $categoria) {
                      ?>
                        <option class="col-md-12" value="<?php $categoria['ID']?>" ><?=$categoria['Nome']?></option>
                      <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <a href="addCurso.php?ID=<?=$categoria['ID'] ?>"><button id="addCurso" type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg btn-block">Criar</button></a>
            </div>
          </form>
```

I only have 2 options: 
ID |  Nome 
 
--------------------
1   |  Programação 
--------------------
2   |  Matemática

It always sends ID: 2 doesn't matter what option I have selected and in addCurso.php I always recieve: null

Comment: If I understand you right then remove yor a tag and put a Submit button. Change your method to Get or change in addCourso.php to $_POST.

Answer (score 1):

your submit button is wrapped into a link (`a`), where you have the last category that was set in the foreach (`addCurso.php?ID=<?=$categoria['ID'] ?>`).. you should remove the `a` tag and let the form post the data to `addCurso.php` which is the form action. it should look like this: `<button id="addCurso" type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg btn-block">Criar</button>` without the `a` tag..

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the code you created is very messy, but I try to explain what you have:

When you do `foreach` in `select`, it will doing :

```
<option class="col-md-12" value="1">Programação</option>
<option class="col-md-12" value="2">Matemática</option>
```

And, it will send last record for your button/link, because the loop is complete :

```
<a href="addCurso.php?ID=2">
    <button id="addCurso" type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg btn-block">Criar</button>
</a>
```

> I don't understand why you need `<a>` (before `<button>`) to submit?

You will always recieve `NULL`, because you don't give a name for your `select`.

Comment: Thank you, it is very messy indeed, I just started learning i'ts the first time i try to use php. I gave a name the select, but I still get NULL on the other php file, probably I'm doing something wrong on the other file too :P

Comment: @FabioFernandes glad to see you solved your issue. Maybe you can clarify or give your best answer to your question.